# My SVG images are not loading

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib

I am currently trying to load several SVG images in a very basic website, but have run in to weird problems. If it is relevant, I am working with SVG files created by matplotlib when graphing various parametric equtions. The file I am trying to load simply loads four random SVG images (all of which work and load fine when I try to load them individually) and put them in a small webpage:

```
<html>
<img src="graphs/{0}.svg">
<img src="graphs/{1}.svg">
<img src="graphs/{2}.svg">
<img src="graphs/{3}.svg">
</html>
```

(The {0} through {3} are replaced with actual file names e.g. 1070). For some reason this fails every time. For example,

```
<html>
<img src="graphs/2286.svg">
<img src="graphs/7499.svg">
<img src="graphs/7444.svg">
<img src="graphs/7666.svg">
</html>
```

Fails even though every one of those links works when I access it individually. I also tried this by directly accessing the html through putting file:///Users/my_name/math_project/file.html as the url, and replacing the {0} etc with numbers, which works. I am at my absolute wits end and if anyone could possibly help me I would be very grateful. This is the source code used to generate the page

```
import socket
import threading
import random
import os
import time
os.chdir("/users/my_name/math_project")
file = open("metadata.txt",'r') # file containing svg file names and equations
svg_data = file.read().split("\n")
file.close()
def handle_call(clientsocket,location): # handles a request
  l = time.time()
  res = clientsocket.recv(100000)
  res = res.split(b"\n")
  request = res[0].split(b" ")[1]
  if request == b"/favicon.ico":
    file = open("favicon.ico",'rb')
    stuff2 = file.read()
    file.close()
    clientsocket.send(stuff2)
  if request == b'/':
    file = open("file.html",'rb')
    res = file.read()
    file.close()
    res = str(res,'utf-8')

    res = res.format(*[random.choice(svg_data).split(":")[0] for a in range(4)])
    clientsocket.send(bytes(res,'utf-8'))
  if request.startswith(b"/graphs/"):
    file = open(place[1:],'rb')
    stuff = file.read()
    file.close()
    clientsocket.send(stuff)
sock = socket.socket()
port = random.randint(2000,10000)
while 1:
  try:
    sock.bind(('',port))
    break
  except BaseException:
    port = random.randint(2000,10000)
print("Bound to port {0}".format(port))
sock.listen(10)
while 1:
  threading.Thread(target=handle_call,args=sock.accept(),).start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your response headers, the web server is returning the SVG files with the wrong Content-Type.

```
Content-Type: image/svg
```

The correct content (MIME) type for SVG files is:

```
Content-Type: image/svg+xml
```

Fix your web server.

Answer (score 1):

One simple thing you can try is designating a doctype in to tell the browser you're using html 5.  You may as well also put the content in the 'body' tag just in case the lack thereof is confusing anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  <img...
  </body>
</html
```

If that doesn't help, would you please clarify what you mean by 'fails'?  What does the output look like, and what does the dev tools 'Network' tab report when it tries to load the images?  Is your sample complete html a copy of the exact output of your program?  If not, can you paste exactly what it's outputting?

Comment: Thank you for this answer. By "fails" I mean shows the default thumbnail image for all four: https://imgur.com/cZq2ajh . The network tab (which I had never heard of before thanks!) gave little information on what was actually going wrong, just that something was going wrong: https://imgur.com/a/BNnTP . That was the first image, and it looked essentially the same for all of the rest. Again I have no idea what's going wrong - I used request to try and see if it could give me more information but it threw no errors and the svg file transmitted fine.

Comment: Paul's response below may be it: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/serve-svg-correct-content-type/